# Difference between clang and g++ in linking a shared library where a symbol already defined in a local object file exists

Tags: c++, g++, clang, shared-libraries

I faced an issue while dealing with a C++ project that I started to work on recently. The project is organized as follows (and I can't change this):

- The core part of the code resides in a central, shared library. I have access to the central library source files, and I can eventually modify the current compilation procedure. For sake of discussion, let's assume that the central library `liba.so` is created by compiling a single file `a.cpp` that contains the two functions `void foo()` and `void bar()`.
- Starting from this core part, multiple executables are created. Each executable resides in its own folder, and it is created by compiling a main code `main.cpp` and, *eventually*, other source codes that are also implementing some of the functions already present in the core library. For sake of discussion, let's assume that there is a file `b.cpp` that contains `void bar()`.

The intended project design is to always give priority to the function defined in the local source codes. The project was tested with g++ on a Linux machine, but it shows a different behavior when compiled with clang on an Apple machine.

*I know that this way of design is probably to be avoided at all, but this is not under my responsibility. I was checking if the project can also be compiled with clang*

This behavior can be reproduced with the following codes:

a.h

```cpp
#ifndef a_h_g 
#define a_h_g 
void foo(); 
void bar(); 
#endif
```

a.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include "a.h" 
void foo(){ 
  std::cout<<"I am foo in a.cpp"<<std::endl; 
  bar(); 
} 

void bar(){ 
  std::cout<<"I am bar in a.cpp"<<std::endl; 
}
```

b.cpp

```cpp
#include "a.h" 
#include <iostream> 
void bar(){ 
  std::cout<<"I AM bar in b.cpp"<<std::endl; 
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "a.h" 
#include <iostream> 
int main(){ 
  std::cout<<"I AM MAIN"<<std::endl; 
  foo(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

and compiling as:

`g++ -fPIC -shared -o liba.so a.cpp`

`g++ -c b.cpp`

`g++ -c main.cpp`

`g++ -o main main.o b.o -L. -la`

When trying this code on a Centos7 machine with g++ version 11.2.0, the result is the one that the project was targeting:

```
I AM MAIN
I am foo in a.cpp
I AM bar in b.cpp
```

Instead, on a MAC with clang version 14.0.0, the result is:

```
I AM MAIN 
I am foo in a.cpp 
I am bar in a.cpp
```

Is there a way to reproduce the Centos7 result with clang?

Comment: Not necessarily your case, but an issue of concern for this setup is function inlining.  ["compilers are free to use inline substitution for any function that's not marked inline"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). Consider requiring each replaceable function for your .so to be in a separate compilation unit.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, indeed the project is organized in such a way, i.e. replaceable functions are in their own compilation unit. For same of simplicity in the above example I coded `foo()` and `bar()` in the same `a.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This difference has *nothing* to do with Clang or GCC, and everything to do with how shared libraries work on different platforms.

On MacOS, the shared library *prefers* symbols defined in the same shared library to those defined globally (similar to how Windows DLLs work).

On Linux, the shared library prefers global symbols, unless the library is linked with `-Bsymbolic` or `-Bsymbolic-functions`.

From MacOS linker [documentation](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ld/):

```
Two-level namespace
  By default all references resolved to a dynamic library record the library
  to which they were resolved. At runtime, dyld uses that information to
  directly resolve symobls. The alternative is to use the -flat_namespace
  option.  With flat namespace, the library is not recorded.

  At runtime, dyld will search each dynamic library in load order when
  resolving symbols. This is slower, but more like how other operating
  systems resolve symbols.
```

You should be able to get a Linux-like behavior by adding `-Wl,-flat_namespace` to `liba.so` link line on MacOS.

> Is there a way to reproduce the Centos7 result with clang?

Sure: just add `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` to `liba.so` link line. From Linux `man ld`:

```
-Bsymbolic
  When creating a shared library, bind references to global symbols
  to the definition within the shared library, if any.  Normally, it is
  possible for a program linked against a shared library to override the
  definition within the shared library.  This option is only meaningful
  on ELF platforms which support shared libraries.
```

Repeating your command:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o liba.so a.cpp
g++ -c b.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o b.o -L. -la -Wl,-rpath=.

./main
I AM MAIN
I am foo in a.cpp
I AM bar in b.cpp
```

Now rebuild `liba.so` with `-Bsymbolic`:

```
$ g++ -fPIC -shared -o liba.so a.cpp -Wl,-Bsymbolic
$ ./main
I AM MAIN
I am foo in a.cpp
I am bar in a.cpp
```